# RSS feed of accepted answers w/ prettify tag classes

Tags: support, accepted-answer, feed, api

Would there be a way to generate an RSS feed of my answers that have been accepted, along with the question body/tags?

I also notice it does not export the prettify classes for `<pre>` tags, is there a way to export those as well in RSS?